# How to add resources folder in core or desktop application in libgdx?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, android-studio-3.0

I am making an desktop 2D game in android studio.I need to add resources files in resource folder.Shall i have to make a folder after src folder and add those files there or should i add resources to assets folder in android and link it up.If yes how do I link it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Game With Android module** : Put your resources inside assets folder of android module , develop and deploy your desktop game.

1. Run using Run/Debug Congiuration

   ```
    Working directory : <project path with name>\android\assets
   ```
2. Run or deploy using Gradle task, check below statement inside gradle file of desktop module

   `project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");` (***default access***)

**Game Without Android module** : Create assets folder inside core module, put all your resources inside that folder.

1. Run using Run/Debug Congiuration

   ```
    Working directory : <project path with name>\core\assets
   ```
2. Run or deploy using Gradle task, check below statement inside gradle file of desktop module

   `project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets");`

---

Open Terminal and run your desktop project using gradle task

`gradlew desktop:run` on Windows or `./gradlew desktop:run` on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

If you like to access the resources from both the desktop and the Android app, put the resources in *core/assets* and add the following line to the `:core` config:

```
project(":core") {

    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = [ "../core/assets" ]
    // ...
}
```

Accessing a font located at *core/assets/font/someFont.ttf* would look like this then:

```
Gdx.files.internal("font/robotoblack.ttf")
```